# What is the name of this technique when the scene is morphed into something visually similar?

Tags: effects, cinematography

Like in the movie *The World's End*, there were some people sitting in the shape of a **circle** then the movie's name is shown gradually, the O letter is similar to the circle made by the people.

I see similar effects in a lot of other works so I was just wondering if this has a name.

Answer (score 5):

After some searching, I found out it's a type of film transition called **Graphic Match Cut**.
[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_transition#Graphic_Match_Cut)

> The cut joins together two pieces of film that contain two similarly
>   shaped objects in similar positions in the frame. One of the most
>   famous examples of this is the edit in Stanley Kubrick's 2001: A Space
>   Odyssey where the bone thrown by a gorilla (man in gorilla costume)
>   cuts to a space station.

And this is the video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtbOmpTnyOc)  (Note:Lower your volume!)

Comment: Your video is dead.